# Import log files from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, logstash

We'r developing project which uploads log files (example below) from logstach into Google Cloud Storage. Then let App Engine import log data into BigQuery. The problem is

1. BigQuery does not accepted some field names such as @timestamp ,created by logstach, in log file. How could I handle this.Can App Engine do anything to solve this?
2. How can I define BigQuery schema for nested JSON (geoip:)?

   {"uuid":"8806ceef34123122cdd009063f301a34158252f53b9a7d3147639fb71f68b585","item_id":1234,"member_id":1234,"admin_id":0,"cate_id":131,"listing_status":3,"monitor_status":2,"note":"","txn_type":"edit","ip_address":"13.89.42.18","email":"xxxx@gmail.com","post_name":"","user_agent":"COM Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0","timestamp":"2014-08-22 06:38:53","http_host":"EA1-ZoneS1",**"@version"**:"1",**"@timestamp**":"2014-08-21T23:38:59.737Z","type":"redis","ua.name":"Firefox","ua.os":"Windows 7","ua.os_name":"Windows 7","ua.device":"Other","ua.major":"31","ua.minor":"0",**"geoip":{"ip":"13.89.42.18","country_code2":"XX","country_code3":"XXX","country_name":"XXXXXXX","continent_code":"AS","region_name":"40","city_name":"XXXX","latitude":123.45,"longitude":123.45,"timezone":"Asia/Bangkok","real_region_name":"XXXXXX","location":[123.45,123.45]}**}

Sorry I'm new. I could not add image.

Please give me suggestion

Thanks.

Comment: As i havent with google App engine, i can tell you about your first query. Actually there is an option in Logstash to remove the fields which is not required. You can ignore the @timestamp field if you dont want it to be in BigQuery.A filter caled `mutate` is used for this.You can find more on this link. http://logstash.net/docs/1.4.2/filters/mutate

Comment: Great Sharma.Even @timestamp filed is come form logstash itself.We could rename it before send it out,right?

Comment: yes user3769827..you are right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You can't use `@` or `.` symbols in names. You'll need to remove them by running the data through something like this.

```
line = line.replace("@", "_")    
line = line.replace("ua.", "ua_")
```

2) You may have to change some types but I was able to load your example data (with the above modifications) using this JSON constructor:

```
[{
    "name": "uuid",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "item_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "member_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "admin_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "cate_id",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "listing_status",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "monitor_status",
    "type": "INTEGER"
}, {
    "name": "note",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "txn_type",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ip_address",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "email",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "post_name",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "user_agent",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
}, {
    "name": "http_host",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "_version",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "_timestamp",
    "type": "TIMESTAMP"
}, {
    "name": "type",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_name",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_os",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_os_name",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_device",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_major",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "ua_minor",
    "type": "STRING"
}, {
    "name": "geoip",
    "type": "RECORD",
    "fields": [{
        "name": "ip",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "country_code2",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "country_code3",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "country_name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "continent_code",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "region_name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "city_name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "latitude",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    }, {
        "name": "longitude",
        "type": "FLOAT"
    }, {
        "name": "timezone",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "real_region_name",
        "type": "STRING"
    }, {
        "name": "location",
        "type": "FLOAT",
        "mode": "REPEATED"
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Hi Bruyere,can you share me script of JSON constructor?

Comment: As in one for constructing the table?

Comment: The constructor that generate the schema above.I'm not sure it is the same as "constructing the table" that you mention or not.

Comment: I did it by hand. You should be able to just use that to create your table. I tested it by going into the admin console and just pasted it in when I created the table

Comment: Yeah,I got your point Bruyere but how do you generate this schema? {"name":"note","type":"STRING"},{"name":"txn_type","type":"STRING"},{"name":"ip_address","type":"STRING"},{"name":"email","type":"STRING"},{"name":"post_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"timestamp","type":"TIMESTAMP"},{"name":"http_host","type":"STRING"},{"name":"_version","type":"STRING"},{"name":"_timestamp","type":"TIMESTAMP"},{"name":"type","type":"STRING"},{"name":"ua_name","type":"STRING"},{"name":"location","type":"FLOAT","mode":"REPEATED"}]}]

Comment: I threw your input into here[1] (after fixing the invalid names) to make it easier to read. then using the example table from here I simply replaced each of the data fields with what seemed most logical to me

[1]http://www.jsoneditoronline.org/
[2]https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/data#nested

Comment: Thanks a lot Bruyere, now I got it.